# How to plot Pandas Dataframe data categorically instead of numerically in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

```
print(final)
    OUTPUT:
             intent sex   age
2        Suicide   F  21.0
3        Suicide   M  60.0
4        Suicide   M  64.0
5        Suicide   M  31.0
7   Undetermined   M  48.0
9     Accidental   M  50.0
11       Suicide   M  30.0
13       Suicide   M  43.0
15      Homicide   M  27.0
17       Suicide   M  55.0
20       Suicide   M  51.0
22       Suicide   F  52.0
24       Suicide   M  19.0
25      Homicide   M  51.0
26      Homicide   M  41.0
28       Suicide   M  21.0
29       Suicide   M  56.0
30      Homicide   M  43.0
32       Suicide   M  55.0
34       Suicide   M  27.0

pro = final['intent'] == 'Suicide'
suicide_df = final[pro]

suicide_df.plot.bar('sex')
plt.ylabel('age')
plt.xlabel('sex')
plt.show()
```

So I just recently started taking some online classes for Data Science using Python and we're on the Panadas library now.

I took a dataset from a csv file of Death rate and now have it in the form of a pandas dataframe that is represented as shown above...

I wish to make the bar graph be categorized by gender so only showing two bars (one for male and one for female) and indicating how many of each died instead of how it is in the image attached. Any guidance appreciated.[Graph of what displays so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZdtz.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

You can try plotting the [`value_counts()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) of the sex column in your `final` dataframe:

```
final.sex.value_counts().plot.bar()
plt.xlabel('sex')
plt.ylabel('number died')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
suicide_df.groupby('sex')['intent'].count().plot.bar()
```

Output:

[image]